# How to check a buttons image in Xcode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am currently trying to find out, whether it is possible to check which image a button uses.

Lets say I have image1 and image2.

If the buttons image is image1 do this and if buttons image is image2 do that.

But xcode doesnt give me any autofill options....

```
[m1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Penguin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This is how i set the images. but how do i find out wheter its Penguin or Penguin2?

Answer (score 7):

Just used This Code for Button Action on the basis of image

```
- (IBAction)checkButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    if ([checkButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"]]) 
        [checkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//do some thing here for your image1

        else
    [checkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //do some thing here for your image 2

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Cocoa Touch was designed around the Model–View–Controller pattern, so you might want to try adopting that pattern. Instead of trying to retrieve state information – the selected penguin – from the view – the button – store it in an instance variable in your controller class.

Your code for setting the image could look like this:

```
self.currentImage = @"Penguin.png";
[m1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: currentImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then when you need to check the value:

```
if ([@"Penguin.png" isEqual:self.currentImage]) {
    do something;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Checking the equality of images is done like so:

```
if ([[UIImage imageNamed:@"Penguin.png"] isEqual:m1.currentImage]) {
    // do something 
}
```

Comment: I don't think this could work, because you are trying to compare two different instances from same father. It should always print false

Comment: This will work only if you set image to m1 from [UIImage imageNamed:] method, because it holds connection all the time it is used, but if you try to set by [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:] it will be always false

Comment: That's right. `+[UIImage imageNamed:]` caches the images it loads, so they'll all be the same. Actually `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Penguin.png" == m1.currentImage` should work. But only if you always create the images using `+imageNamed:`.

Answer (score 3):

2 methods can be used for this:

1.

```
UIImage *image = self.myButton.currentBackgroundImage;
```

2.

```
myImageView.image = [myButton backgroundImageForState:myButton.state];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UIImage *img=[(UIButton *) sender currentImage];   

if(img == [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit"])
{  
    //If do something
 }`
```

try this hope it will work

Comment: If it not work add @"edit.png" or which  format of image. for me its working properly

Answer (score 1):

In Swift also possible

iOS 8+

```
if button.currentImage?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "Penguin.png")) {
        //do something here
    }
```

iOS 7-

```
if timerButton.currentImage ==  UIImage(named: "Penguin.png") {
        //do something here
    }
```